# Implicit value polymorphism in Scala and Spray

Tags: scala, oop, implicit, spray, spray-json

I'm trying to create a common trait for my Actors to avoid code copypasting, basically like this:

```
import akka.actor.Actor
import spray.json._

import scala.concurrent.Future

trait ActorResponsive[T] extends Actor {
  import DefaultJsonProtocol._
  import context.dispatcher

  case class Response(success: Boolean,
                      single: Option[T] = None,
                      multiple: Option[Seq[T]] = None,
                      message: Option[String] = None)

  implicit val responseFormat = jsonFormat4(Response)

  def makeResponse(f: Future[Any]) =
    f.map { /*...*/ }.recover { /*...*/ }
        .map { case r => r.toJson.compactPrint }
}
```

Regardless other code flaws, I'm trying to make `responseFormat` resolved polymorphically, e.g.:

```
class PostgresItemActor extends ActorResponsive[Item] {
  import com.blahblah.models.ItemJsonProtocol._
  override def receive = makeResponse(someFuture)
}
...
class PostgresEventActor extends ActorResponsive[Event] {
  import com.blahblah.models.EventJsonProtocol._
  override def receive = makeResponse(someFuture)
}
```

So JsonProtocol for each time `responseFormat` is called will be resolved regarding the import in the class, implementing the `ActorResponsive` trait. As for now, I'm getting a compile error:

```
Cannot find JsonWriter or JsonFormat type class for ActorResponsive.this.Response
```

Probably I'm getting some concept of OOP wrong here, but is it possible to resolve `jsonFormat(Response)` for `T` or achieve some behaviour like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to provide the `JsonWriter` as a parameter to your `makeResponse` function.

Something along the lines of:

```
def makeResponse[T: JsonWriter](f: Future[T]) =
  f.map { /*...*/ }.recover { /*...*/ }
    .map { case r => r.toJson.compactPrint }
```

Comment: Thanks, I've managed to do this with such a function:
`def makeResponse(f: Future[Any])(implicit writer: spray.json.JsonWriter[Response[T]], executor: scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext) = ...`